# How to combine the use of Lazy Loding and parameterized routes in Angular

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular-router

I currently have a working Angular 4 application with parameterized route with variables placeholders i.e. `:zoneId` `:schemaId` `:id` . I do not want to get rid of these but now that we are converting our app to use lazy loading, I cannot figure out where these parameterized routes go.

Currently
app-routing.module.ts(which is imported into app-module.ts) has

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
 {
        path: 'zones/:zoneId/schemas/:schemaId/errands/:id',
        component: ErrandDetailComponent
```

but all the examples I'm following such as these

https://toddmotto.com/lazy-loading-angular-code-splitting-webpack
https://medium.com/@kouipheng.lee/lazy-loading-with-angular-4-29c23792b7f4

seemed to make me wipe away this path and give a generic name and use the `loadChildren` router which requires the path of the module `#SomeModuleName` This would make my code look something like this:

```
    const ROUTES: Routes = [
     {
            path: 'errandDetailComponent',
            loadChildren: './items/errands/errand-routing.module#ErrandRoutingModule',
            component: ErrandDetailComponent
```

**Here is my issue because I don't know where I can use my parameterized routes now.**

Just for completeness, my child router looks like this:

```
const errandRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', // APPARENTLY THIS MUST BE EMPTY FOR LAZY LOADING TO WORK SO CAN'T PUT PARAMETERIZED PATH IN HERE EITHER
        component: ErrandDetailComponent,
        resolve: { errand: ErrandResolver },
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(errandRoutes)
    ],
    declarations: [ErrandRoutingModule],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
})
export class ErrandRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this setup you can use child routes to add the parameters back in.

#### app-routing.module.ts

```js
const ROUTES: Routes = [
 {
      path: 'zones',
      loadChildren: './items/errands/errand-routing.module#ErrandRoutingModule',
```

#### errands-routing.module.ts

```js
const errandRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ErrandsComponent,
        children: [{
            path: ':zoneId/schemas/:schemaId/errands/:id',
            component: ErrandDetailComponent,
            resolve: { errand: ErrandResolver },
        }]
    }
];
```

And you will just need a very thin `ErrandsComponent` for displaying the detail component.

#### errands.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-errands',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
})
export class ErrandsComponent{}
```

Comment: I think this is the correct way. It did not work for me though but I think it is because we have an overly complex structure for our routers. Though we haven't figured it out yet, this helped set us in the right path.